# Sending bytes greater than 0x7F with SerialPort Object

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a need to send bytes through the serial port and wanted to do this using the convenience of the C# class SerialPort. However it apperas there is a severe restriction on sending raw bytes through the serial port using this class as, quoting from the [ASCIIEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) class docs:

> ASCIIEncoding corresponds to the Windows code page 20127. Because ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F. If you use the default encoder returned by the Encoding.ASCII property or the ASCIIEncoding constructor, characters outside that range are replaced with a question mark (?) before the encoding operation is performed.

This is NOT what I want. If I have a byte value greated than 0x7F I want it sent as that value, NOT encoding as a question mark. I cannot use UTF-8 encoding as this can introduce more bytes for characters which my receiving device does not expect. Both [SerialPort.Write Method (Char[], Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1050fs1h.aspx) and (stupidly in my opinion) [SerialPort.Write Method (Byte[], Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx) encode the data prior to transmission.

It appears that I can create my own [EncoderFallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderfallback.aspx) class but from my understanding this only allows me to specify another character to use instead of '?' or am I incorrect in assuming this?

So is it at all possible to send bytes that have NOT been interferred with via the SerialPort class?

Comment: SerialPort will send **raw bytes**, if you do not encode them then you won't get question marks or anything else.

Comment: I think that is a property of the serial port. IOW nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I mean: the Serial.Port(byte[], int, int) shares the Remarks section with other overloads but the paragraph about encoding applies only to methods that works with strings, not with raw bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a comment on the [`byte[]` overload page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551):

> The remarks about ASCIIEncoding and the other types of encoding do not apply to this overload. This overload uses byte arrays, bypassing the encoding.
>
> (It looks like these encoding remarks were copy/pasted from the other overloads of Write. Those overloads - using character arrays and strings - do use the encoding).
>
> — Micah Copple (possibly user [mjcopple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279999/mjcopple) - should be able to 'forward' reputation!)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see those remarks! It makes sense that the bytes are indeed left untouched.

Comment: This is still not fixed in the documentation. Very confusing

Comment: @rkgghz just submitted a PR to remove this text https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/8274